# Chained Relations on CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm new to CakePHP and I'm still trying to understand relationships between classes, class names and table names. I've tried to find an answer before asking, but I'm afraid I didn't know what should I search for.

So I'm a freelance developer and I'm trying to accomplish two objectives:

- Build an webpage to have account of my budgets, projects, clients, invoices, etc.
- Learn CakePHP

Fortunately I should be able to do both things at the same time :)

So, I have a list of *budgets* that, over time, will change of *status*. As I want to have a history of those status changes, I'm not replacing (updating) the status on the database, I'll be adding a new row every time there is a status change. So I'll have three tables: one for budgets, another for statuses and a third table containing the name of those statuses.

What I did on CakePHP:

- Class `Budget`, table `budgets`
- Class `BudgetStatus`, table `budget_statuses`
- Class `BudgetStatusName`, table `budgets_status_names`

The main classes, relevant to this question, are:

**Budget**

```
class Budget extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Client' => array(
            'className' => 'Client'
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Status' => array(
            'className' => 'BudgetStatus',
            'order'     => 'Status.date DESC',
            'dependent' => TRUE
        )
    );

}
```

**BudgetStatus**

```
class BudgetStatus extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
        'StatusName' => array(
            'className' => 'BudgetStatusName'
        )
    );

}
```

**BudgetStatusName**

```
class BudgetStatusName extends AppModel {

}
```

**BudgetsController**

```
class BudgetsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index() {
        $this->set('budgets', $this->Budget->find('all', array('order' => array('Budget.date' => 'desc'))));
    }

    public function view($id) {
        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }

        $budget = $this->Budget->findById($id);
        if (!$budget) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }
        $this->set('budget', $budget);
    }
}
```

On **View/Budgets/view.ctp** I wrote `pr($budget);`, then when I access **/budgets/view/1** I see this structure:

```
Array
(
    [Budget] => Array
        (
            [id]
            [date]
            [client_id]
            [title]
            [description]
            [status]
            [created]
            [modified]
        )

    [Client] => Array
        (
            [id]
            [name]
            [created]
            [modified]
        )

    [Status] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id]
                    [budget_id]
                    [budgets_status_names_id]
                    [amount]
                    [details]
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id]
                    [budget_id]
                    [budgets_status_names_id]
                    [amount]
                    [details]
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id]
                    [budget_id]
                    [budgets_status_names_id]
                    [amount]
                    [details]
                )

        )

)
```

So, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I expected to get the status names for every element inside [Status]

Are the table names, classes names and column names ok?

Thank you in advance, and sorry for my English :)

PS: If you're wondering what does the data on the database looks like, this is an example (I just show only the columns relevant to this question).

```
budgets
id | client_id | title

budget_statuses
id | budget_id | date | budgets_status_names_id

budget_status_names
id | name

clients
id | name
```

Answer (score 2):

budgets_status_names_id should be budget_status_name_id in the budget_statuses table.

Also in order to get more levels deep of associated data, you should use containable

```
$this->Budget->find('all', array(
    'order' => array('Budget.date' => 'desc')),
    'contain' => array('Client', 'Status' => array('StatusName'))
));
```

Add the following to your AppModel:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Comment: Note, you were not consistent with your tablenames in the post. you mix up budgets_status_names table name and budget_status_names. The latter would match your model

Comment: Hi Ceeram, thank you!. I still can't get status names. I noticed in your example you're using Budget->find('all').

But I don't need that information on the budget list. I need that on the budget detailed view (Views/Budget/view.ctp)

On that view I'm showing information about the budget (columns of budgets table). Below there is a table listing all the status changes, one row for every status (columns of budget_statuses) where one column is budget_status_name_id (tinyint). I want to show the status name instead of it's id, the name is stored in budget_status_names.name.

Comment: More info: The view shows information about one particular budget (**Budget->findById()**). One of the html <table> column <td> shows the budget_statuses.budget_status_name_id column, instead I want to show budget_status_names.name (where budget_status_names.id = budget_statuses.budget_status_name_id) for every budget_statuses rows about a particular budget (where budget_statuses.budget_id = budgets.id). Thank you in advance :)